# How do I run code while my app is starting up underneath the splash screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, splash-screen

I'm trying to be able to run code in the background while my iOS app is starting up. I have to call a few APIs which may take a few seconds to get information for the first page of the app, and I want to make it look seamless, so I want all that API loading to take place while the splash screen is open.

How can I accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: Just place the code inside your App Delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Answer (score 3):

If you set up the launchImage in the project general properties, then whatever you have in the appDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, before you call the main viewController will be done in the "background" while the launchImage or splashScreen is seen.

[image]

Another thing you can do, is make the appDelegate load an initial viewController that just has a UIImageView that takes up the whole screen, or just a background image for the main UIView. In this view controller you can make any calculations you want, and save the data you need, and when all of that is complete, you can then load the main view controller you intended to load.
A small pseudo code for this could be like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
  //do calculations
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      //load main view controller
    });
});
```